# What is branch coverage?

Tags: testing, flowchart

I am preparing myself for ISTQB exam and I came across this question.

> For the code fragment given below, which answer correctly represents
>   minimum tests required for statement and branch coverage respectively?
>
> ```
> Discount rate=1;
> Fare = 1000;
> If ((person == “senior citizen”) and (“travel month = January”))
> Bonuspoints = 100+Bonuspoints
> If (class==”first”)
> discountRate = .5;
> Fare = fare * discountRate;
> ```
>
> - a. Statement Coverage = 1, Branch Coverage = 2
> - b. Statement Coverage = 2, Branch Coverage = 2
> - c. Statement Coverage = 1, Branch Coverage = 3
> - d. Statement Coverage = 2, Branch Coverage = 4

Answer is **A**

But my answer is **C** the reason is flowchart I draw for it given below.

1. Straight forward from start to end
2. One false for 1st 'if'
3. second false for 2nd 'if'

[image: Flow chart]

My question is:

1. Should we draw an edge 'explicitly' for 'false' condition, if it is not given in question itself.
2. How branch coverage is 2 here ?

Comment: The scope of conditionals in the code does not correspond to those on float chart, as far as I can see. Can you make it more explicit, e..g by indentation,?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229236/differences-between-line-and-branch-coverage

Answer (score 3):

#### To calculate Statement Coverage

Find out the shortest number of paths following which all the nodes will be covered.
Here in this Flow chart I have defined Nodes and edges as below:

1. 1,2 3, etc are Nodes
2. A, B, C etc are Edges

With path `1A-2B-3C-4D-5G-6G-7H`, all nodes 1,2,3... 7 is covered.
So, Statement Coverage will be 1 as no other path we need here to cover all nodes.

#### To calculate Branch Coverage

Find out the minimum number of paths which will ensure covering of all the edges.

With path `1A-2B-3C-4D-5G-6G-7H`, we have covered 1 side edge in this flow chart (I, J is remaining)

for that path will be

```
1A-2B-3I-5J  
1A-2B-3C-4D-5G-6G-7H
```

By the combining the above two paths we can ensure of traveling through all the paths so correct answer is:-

> a. Statement Coverage = 1, Branch Coverage = 2

**Flow Chart :-**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe your diagram/Flowchart is incorrect.

It makes more sense to me that both **IF** statements will Always be run. A 'False' result in the First **IF** statement will mean that the code will then execute the 2nd If statement.

**Test 1** will cover positive scenarios. Both of your **IF** statements will be TRUE, meaning a full pass through all positive outcomes of your conditional  statements

**Test 2** will provide False to the first **IF** statement, and then again False to the second **IF** statement, which covers all the negative outcomes of this branch.